# How to fit a regression line into seaborn scatterplot

Tags: regression, data-visualization, seaborn

I have the following pandas where data.head() shows the table below:

```
          Country     LifeExp   Year        Continent
     0    USA         88        2022       Americas
     1    UK          78        2022       Europe
     2    UAE         78        2022       Asia
     3    Pakistan    98        2022       Asia
```

I want to plot the years against life expectancy for a total of 100 different years and 100 different countries.

I have tried `seaborn.scatterplot(x='year',y='lifeExp',hue='continent',data=data)`
to draw the scatter plot needed, however I don't know how to fit a regression line to the scatter plot I just made, as this function doesn't seem to be having an option for them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `seaborn.lmplot(...)`. I tried it with your df.head() as data (only four data points).

```
print(data)
#    Country  LifeExp  Year Continent
#0       USA       88  2022  Americas
#1        UK       78  2022    Europe
#2       UAE       78  2022      Asia
#3  Pakistan       98  2022      Asia
```

With lmplot,

```
seaborn.lmplot(x='Year',y='LifeExp',hue='Continent',data=data)
```

[image: lm]

With scatterplot

```
seaborn.scatterplot(x='Year',y='LifeExp',hue='Continent',data=data)
```

[image: scatter]

Comment: it's the correct way but looks really weird with 1 data point lol.. I hope OP provides something or explain where he/she is stuck.